# How to ignore Proxy for redirected URLs in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I've a website which has two hosts. *mywebsite.a.com* which uses proxy and *mywebsite.b.com* which should not use proxy. Now the *mywebsite.a.com* is redirecting the request to *mywebsite.b.com* along with proxy authentication resulting in connection reset error for *mywebsite.b.com*. How to overcome this error?

I've tried below options:

1. Launch Jmeter with proxy settings **jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N mywebsite.b.com**
2. Add proxy in advanced tab for only http requests which uses *mywebsite.a.com* but no luck

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by by following below steps.

1. Create the req 1 with proxy enabled in advanced tab
2. Uncheck the Follow Redirects option in req 1
3. Capture the redirected request location in response headers
4. Create new request (req 2) with details captured in previous request and run the scripts now